# How to transfer an optimization problem written with GUROBI (in python) in a grammar that can be readily solved with another solver?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, python, gurobi, pyomo, pulp

Trying to use an opensource optimization tool in python (having used only gurobi for years) I see that the whole code (representing the optimization problem in pythonic language) must be written differently in order to use such tools (pyomo etc.). Is there a straightforward way for me to run my scripts (in the form that they are written-aligning with gurobi grammar) but using a different solver/tool/package rather than gurobi?

Answer (score 4):

I think [pySCIPOpt](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt) might be a good choice, provided you are willing to make minor changes to the code.  The modelling interface is very similar to Gurobi and the underlying SCIP solver also supports handy modelling features like indicator constraints or logical AND/OR/XOR constraints. Alternatively, you could save all your models as MPS files and solve them with the solver of your choice since nearly all common modelling interfaces support the MPS file format.

Comment: thank you very much!